# Why Unit test of WebServer project shows strange behaviour?

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, maven, junit, webserver

I am writing Unit test of my project *HTTP THREADPOOLED WEB SERVER*. For that I am using **Junit** in **Maven**.

In the mean while I stuck in one place, and the doubt is as follows,

1. There is one class named *WebServer*, whose task is to start the server, makes threadpool, and starts listening on the port for client request. When I make a thread for the same, in the Test class under annotation `@BeforeClass`, it is expected to wait for the client request , but it comes out shows Test completes.

   public class WebServerTest {

   ```
   @BeforeClass
   public static void webserverStarter() {
       System.out.println("Before Class : webserverStarter");
       new Thread(new WebServer()).start();
   }

   @AfterClass
   public static void webserverCleanup() {
       System.out.println("After Class : webserverStarter");
   }
   ```

   }

I don't understand why this not waits for client request. Please help me in writing the unit test for testing HTTP Threadpooled WebServer.

Answer (score 0):

The @Before are executed before every single Test. If you want to use one single Webserver, just make an object!

Comment: But, please me why it comes out successfully, when in WebServer Class , there is a infity loop, in which server is accepting client request.

It should not be come out from webserver class normally.

Comment: This is comand in infinity loop `client_socket = serversocket.accept();`.Tell me how can I accept client request? Is there any method, so that I can replace this socket by any other InputStream of any file in resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that webserverStarter() is actually starting the server, there is no doubt that the server will work. Don't worry about the annotation @BeforeClass. It only mean that it will be called only once and the same thing apply to @AfterClass.

What I suspect is that, if your server is actually started, and you are sure about it, **may be the server got shut down immediately after it starts successfully or after the test case ends successfully**. In am using Embedded Tomcat server in which I have to tell my server to run continuously like this.

```
tomcat.start();     
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

Comment: Can you explain the last line, please.

Comment: Embedded Tomcat is a server for testing. Example, http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal  tomcat.start();  will start the server but you have to say tomcat.getServer().await(); to run continuously.

Comment: One thing I want to make you clear is that , I made my own server, just for learning  multithreading, socket concepts.

Comment: JUNIT test case is designed not to run forever. I still suspect that after @AfterClass is called, your test case ends successfully and it stops all the inner threads along with it.